# How to install language packs for all existing and new users

Tags: windows-10, powershell, language-pack

I have to install 5 languages in an already Windows 10 installation :

```
"fr-FR","ro-RO","es-ES","it-IT","en-GB"
```

I have tried :

```
$languagePacks = @("fr-FR","ro-RO","es-ES","it-IT","en-GB")
foreach ($language in $languagePacks) {
    echo "=> Installing $language ..."
    Install-Language $language
}
```

How to install language packs for all existing and new users from CLI ?

Comment: What have you tried? The answer the question about `Get-WinUserLanguageList `just suggested a way to list the active user's culture settings. Neither of which will install language packs on any version of Windows 10. My suggestion add the language packs to the .wim then install Windows from that modified Windows image.

Comment: `Install-Language` only downloads the Language Pack.  You would have to actually set the interface language in a separate command or use `-CopyToSettings` to set the default and system locale.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-copytosettings

Comment: @Ramhound I have updated my question which was a somehow confusing. Does the `-CopyToSettings` option copy the languages for all the existing and new users accounts ?

Comment: You will have to read the description yourself.  It configures what the default and system locale settings are on the system. Your code does not make sense.  You loop through an array of strings, to only install the same language, multiple times.  Sounds like you need SO more than SU

Comment: @Ramhound Oups :) That was copy/paste typo, it is fixed now.

Comment: @Ramhound It seems a reboot is also necessary for the newly installed languages to appear in the language selection list. Thanks for your help.