# PowerShell es-es Language Installation: ErrorCode -2147418113

Tags: windows-10, powershell, language-pack

I'm trying to install [language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2022-ps) with PowerShell run as admin on another computer but it fails with the `ErrorCode: -2147418113` :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Language es-es
Install-Language : Failed to install language. ErrorCode: -2147418113. Please try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Language es-es
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotInstalled: (:) [Install-Language], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToInstallLanguage,Microsoft.LanguagePackManagement.Powershell.Commands.InstallLanguage

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Is by any chance the wi-fi connection on that computer is set as "metered connection"?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not using Wi-Fi here.

Comment: What is the difference between your computer and this one?

Comment: [Yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/1809249/how-to-install-language-packs-for-all-existing-and-new-users) you made it sound like this command worked. What changed?

Comment: @Ramhound It's another computer.

Comment: @harrymc They both are using Win10-22H2. That's all I know.

Comment: What edition is this installation? You have to give us more? There must be a difference between the two machines. Only you can identify that differences

Comment: Hi @SebMa ... Have you had an opportunity to try any of the solutions I suggested in the provided answer? I'm looking forward to hearing your feedback on the results when you have a moment.

Comment: Make sure you have updated versions of both your `powershell` (core) and `winget`. Then use: `winget install -e --id 'Microsoft.PowerShell'`. And run as admin...

Answer (score 1):

As listed in [Install-Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2022-ps), you can also change your **display language** by using the International module commands ([Set-WinUILanguageOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride?view=windowsserver2022-ps) ).

It is worth noting to not overlook and consider further troubleshooting such as:

- elevated PowerShell running as administrator with PowerShell cmdlets
- logging/signing off and then back on to the Windows user account for effectiveness

  - restarting the system
- using other correlated system language cmdlet such as:

  - `Set-WinUILanguageOverride`
  - `Set-WinUserLanguageList`
  - `Set-WinSystemLocale`

Furthermore, run this PowerShell to get a list of cmdlets which allow management of language and regional settings for users on Windows 10.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name International | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExportedCommands
```

### Additional troubleshooting things

1. If this machine is pointing to a WSUS server within the registry, sometimes this can cause problems with installing feature packs and modules. Run this PowerShell to disallow WSUS Windows Update pointers from being effective, then retry the language commands.

```
$WUServer = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU").UseWUServer;
If($WUServer){New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\" -Name "UseWUServer" -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force};
Restart-Service -Name wuauserv -Force;
```

> [`UseWUServer` (`REG_DWORD`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wu-settings#configuring-automatic-updates-by-editing-the-registry)
>
> Set this value to `1` to configure Automatic Updates to use a server that is running Software Update Services instead of Windows Update.

2. If there are conflicting local group policies on the machine, and those configurations are not of importance, run the below PowerShell to wipe the local group policies, reboot, then then retry the language commands.

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers";
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy"
gpupdate /force /wait:0;
```

3. If you are in a domain joined environment on domain joined machines, it might be beneficial to reach out to the domain administrators. It's possible to have domain group policies enforced to some machines but not others causing you issues.
4. Ensure all Windows Updates are installed and that Windows is up-to-date, and has been restarted to make pending Windows Updates effective.
5. Run a [Windows Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/disk-cleanup-in-windows-8a96ff42-5751-39ad-23d6-434b4d5b9a68) with the below PowerShell to pick all the files and system files to cleanup, let it finish, reboot, and then retry the language commands. Ensure disk space if available for growth too.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\*' | ForEach-Object {
New-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name StateFlags0001 -Value 2 -PropertyType DWord -Force};
Start-Process -FilePath CleanMgr.exe -ArgumentList '/sagerun:1'
```

6. Running PowerShell admin elevated `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` followed by `sfc /scannnow` and a reboot could be useful too helping fix corruption.

### Supporting Resources

- [International Settings Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852115.aspx)
- [**Install-Language**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

  > Installs a language onto a device.
  >
  > **Description**
  >
  > Downloads and installs the available language components for the
  > specified language onto a device.
  >
  > ***You can also change your Display Language by using the International
  > module commands (`Set-WinUILanguageOverride <lnstalled Language>`)***
- [**Set-WinUILanguageOverride**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

  > Sets the Windows UI language override setting for the current user
  > account.
  >
  > **Description**
  >
  > The `Set-WinUILanguageOverride` cmdlet sets a user-preferred display
  > language to be used for the Windows user interface (UI). If no
  > override setting is used, the display language is dynamically
  > determined from the language list of the user. ***Log off and logging
  > back on is required for changes to take place.***
  >
  > For more information, see the [`Get-WinUserLanguageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winuserlanguagelist?view=windowsserver2022-ps) and
  > [`Set-WinUserLanguageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=windowsserver2022-ps) cmdlets.
- [**Set-WinSystemLocale**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winsystemlocale?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

  > Sets the system locale for the current computer.
  >
  > **Description**
  >
  > The `Set-WinSystemLocale` cmdlet **sets the system locale for the
  > current computer**. The System-locale setting determines which code
  > pages, which include ANSI, DOS, and Macintosh, the computer uses by
  > default. If you change the System-locale setting, the necessary bitmap
  > font files are installed to support legacy applications in the
  > selected language.
  >
  > **This is a system setting. It can only be changed by a user who has Administrator permissions. Changes take effect after the computer is
  > restarted.**

Comment: Also consider if this system has antivirus or endpoint security configurations on it, and poking thru the Event Viewer logs never hurts either in case you see something related stick out helping narrow down further perhaps.

Comment: It might be worth checking out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs-for-windows-a5094319-a92d-18de-5b53-1cfc697cfca8 and seeing if you notice anything with those GUI level steps already configured differently between the two machines.

Comment: Super great answer. Can you say a bit more about what `step 6` does?

Comment: From Powershell admin elevated prompt, paste in `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, press enter, wait for it to complete. Then run `sfc /scannnow` from the same or another elevated Powershell prompt, let it complete, and then reboot. More technical detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image?view=windows-11 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e @not2qubit Thank you!

Comment: @not2qubit "*An online Windows image repair*" ==> `DISM` and "*repair missing or corrupted system files*" ==> `SFC` basically!

Comment: Sure, that can anyone google. But it is inherently unclear what these two tools actually do. Different info in different places. Ie. How does `/restorehealth` actually restore "health"? Where are the files takes and how does it decide which ones are in need of replacement?

Comment: @not2qubit I'm unsure how `DISM` decides which files to replace, but examining its internal operations through traces & memory dumps might offer insights. Personally, I haven't attempted this. When using `/RestoreHealth`, `DISM` defaults to Windows Updates for replacements, & you can specify an alternative source with another parameter, detailed in the documentation via the comment URL. Whether this is definitively answerable may require a separate question about it specifically. 
These commands are recommended as last-resort troubleshooting steps, not a detailed breakdown of their workings.

Comment: All in the context of this specific post's question of course^^