# Windows 11 Update error: We couldn't connect to the update service

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-update

I am running Windows 11 Pro 22H2 64-bit on a Dell Precision 5530 Laptop (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz 32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable) - Product Id 00330-54920-19766-AAOEM).

Recently, when I try to run Windows Update, I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried all the "fixes" suggested [here](https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/we-couldnt-connect-to-the-update-service.html), [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-update-we-couldnt-connect-to-the-update/02750666-61ea-48b6-9e20-2221dbc24e5e), and [here](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-windows-update-in-windows-11.3808/), to no avail.

Specifically, I have attempted the following:

1. Disabling all third-party antivirus/antimalware software (in my case, MalwareBytes and Hitman Pro.  I ran full scans with both products first before disabling them, just to make sure a virus wasn't causing my problems).
2. Running the Windows Update Troubleshooter.
3. Changing my DNS settings to point to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for primary and secondary DNS servers, respectively.
4. Deleting everything inside the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution after stopping wuauserv, cryptSvc, bits, and msiserver (and starting them again after rebooting my PC).
5. Running `sfc /scannow` (which indicated that there were no corrupted system files).
6. Running the batch file `Reset_Reregister_Windows_Update_Components_for_Windows11.bat`, which I downloaded from [here](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-windows-update-in-windows-11.3808/).

I've searched extensively and have not found a fix.  Any suggestions (other than manually searching the Microsoft Update Catalog)?

Comment: Can someone please help me with this?  Surely this is a common problem with a simple solution - right?

Comment: Try to do [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/) to set Windows to a known cohesive state. This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade while keeping all apps and settings, but take some backups.

Comment: @CadeBryant Try suggestions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1766039/powershell-microsoft-update-session-unable-to-download-all-updates/1766702#1766702 to start, then look here: https://superuser.com/questions/1809352/powershell-language-installation-errorcode-2147418113/1809387#1809387 for the cleanmgr steps, and lastly check over items here you've not run should you still have issues:  https://superuser.com/questions/1113553/downloading-windows-updates-takes-forever/1115225#1115225. Start with the 1st link, see if that resolves then move to next and try it if not.

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for all the comments.  I tried the Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade that @harrymc suggested, but the "Fix Problems using Windows Update" option was missing from the settings.  I will try Vomit IT's suggestions when I am back in town (I had to leave town on the 15th and had to leave that PC behind).  Thanks again.

Comment: Use Option Two : [Repair Install Windows 11 using ISO or USB Installation Media](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/#Two).

Answer (score 0):

So for a bit of context:

When you update windows, you are connecting to a WSUS (Windows Server Update Service). It would be worth checking the configuration to see which WSUS server you connect to.

You mentioned that you didnt want to manually search the update catelog. I offer a slightly different approach:

Look for the updates that it is having trouble installing, install them yourself, restart, and have it check again. For convenience, the update catelog URL is:  https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx and search for the specific update windows is claiming it cannot install.

Additionally, you should check your IP6 settings and see if they are interfering in anyway.

If you are able to provide more details after this, I can further assist.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, consider WSUS Offline, https://www.wsusoffline.net, which can be used to retrieve all the necessary updates and store them on a thumb drive or local HD. You may need to do the fetch from a separate computer if yours can't see the Microsoft WSUS; but once you have the updates on a thumb drive you should be able to invoke the update process ithout ever going out to the net.